# Draggable UIImgeView Rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, rotation, drag

I have a UIImageView object that I rotate with frame property and CFAffineTransformMakeRotate and then I want ot move it with moving origin of its frame, but my image moves and reshape strangly.

```
 @implementation TimberView
```

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
  {
  // Retrieve the touch point
  CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
  startLocation = pt;
  [[self superview] bringSubviewToFront:self];
  }
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
  {
  // Move relative to the original touch point
  CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
  CGRect frame = [self frame];

  frame.origin.x += pt.x - startLocation.x;
  frame.origin.y += pt.y - startLocation.y;
  [self setFrame:frame];
  }

The TimberView class is a subclass of UIImageView

Comment: Could you post the code where you move your view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from UIView's frame property reference:

> If the transform property is also
>   set, use the bounds and center
>   properties instead; otherwise,
>   animating changes to the frame
>   property does not correctly reflect
>   the actual location of the view.

So if you apply some custom transform to your view you cannot use view's frame property. To move the view change its `center` property instead, so your code should be transformed to (not sure if the code is correct or not):

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    // Move relative to the original touch point
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    CGPoint newCenter;

    newCenter.x += pt.x - startLocation.x;
    newCenter.y += pt.y - startLocation.y;
    [self setCenter: newCenter];
}
```

If you want just to position view's center to touched point you can use the following code:

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView: [self superview]];
self.center = touchPoint;
```

Comment: thnks, when i use your first code the shape blinks and don't move just in the direction of touch but your seccond code works, it has some little problems that I think I can solve them. (forexample when i touch a point on the shape, its center move to there and after that i can drag it)